# How can I increase the speed MySQL stored procedure call in C#

Tags: mysql, .net, stored-procedures

I'm trying to collect a stream of data (100-150 packets per second) and then send processed packets to MySQL database using a stored procedure:

```
comm = new MySqlCommand("cantm_insert", conn);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_tmsid", tmsid);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_time", DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_dest", c.Identifier >> 3);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_source", c[0]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_length", c.DataLength);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_type", c[1]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?_data", buffer);

comm.executeNonQuery();
```

This method give me only 15-20 packets per second to store in database. 
I need to store the data into database as soon as possible.

In MSSQL I could send the big packet of text commands (like "select * from tbl;insert into tbl;delete from tbl;"), but I have no idea how to increase the performance using the stored procedure.

Comment: this is unclear what you're doing. Please explain from where your "packets" are coming from, how to retrieve them, and what's your global (yet summarised) architectural solution

Comment: 900 - 1200 stored procedure calls per minute is not a terrible level of performance.  6000 - 9000 procedure calls per minute would be a very high level of performance indeed, requiring good hardware and properly optimized software. Getting this level of performance will not be easy. This is especially true if there's a simultaneous query load on the same MySQL server. That's why @Sebas asked for more detail.

Comment: these packets are going from CAN bus and the test could be in action for a couple of hours. I need to store all the CAN packets into the database for postprocess it in future.

Comment: how can i concatenate two or more MySqlCommands in one datapacket, like batch command "insert into...;insert into...;insert into...;" (delimited by semicolon)? This string is only limited by maximum server packet size and the type should be CommandType.CommandText.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your code's performance by reusing the command & parameter objects.
As you acquire new datapoints simply set values to the parameter objects.
All the resource allocations will hurt code's performance.
Don't know what your sproc is doing so can't help there.

On the DB side, drop indexes. You might implement a data collection table which is truncated  before starting the test. After the test move the data to its 'real' table.

You mention 150-200 packets/sec for data stream. Is this an average or continuous data?
Because if packets come in bursts, you could use one thread for data collection & a second thread for db storage with a buffer/queue between them. Verify that the buffer gets processed before the next data burst. This way you won't drop data.

Comment: +1 for object reuse and dropping indexes. I would add to add to try to keep also the Connection opened during the whole process lifetime.